# Typo3 FAL show file browser popup in backend module

Tags: browser, module, popup, typo3, backend

I have a site which shows a teaser (image+text) on all pages.
This should be editable from admin, so I created a small backend module (a simple form) where the admin should set the image and the text and save them in Typo3's registry db table:

This is how I save the text:

```
$request = $this->controllerContext->getRequest();
$arguments = $request->getArguments();
$registry = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance( 't3lib_Registry' );
$extKey = $request->getControllerExtensionKey();

$registry->set( $extKey, 'text', $arguments['settings']['text'] );
```

but I don't know how to add an "Add image" link to display the file browser and get the url/id of the selected file.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a file picker you will need to have a TCA for a FAL field. A TCA is usually connected to a table and I wouldn't know of any implementation with the registry as a "storage backend".

This means you would have to create TCEForms yourself and then intercept the saving process. This is possible but rarely used and rather complicated, see an example here:
https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git/blob/TYPO3_4-5:/typo3/sysext/version/ws/workspaceforms.php
(for TYPO3 4.x, for 6.x the class names have to be adjusted)

So I would suggest that you extend the table pages with a field for text and a FAL field instead of trying to write an own backend module for this purpose.